# Splitting large numbers with commas

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've just finished a bit of code but realised once i start entering larger numbers everything began to seem a bit messy and un-organised.
I decided i'd try to format the numbers from how python displays them to how you would write them in real life:

*Example*: `4567082` into `4,567,082` or `560867956` into `560,867,956`, etc.

After trying this for a little while however, i came up with nothing. Just wondering as to what a solution for this may be if anyone knows.

Answer (score -1):

```
n1 = 4567082
n2 = 560867956
n3 = 120

def add_char(n, char):
    sn = str(n)
    rn = sn[::-1]
    return char.join(rn[s:s+3] for s in range(0, len(sn), 3))[::-1]

print(add_char(n1, ','))
print(add_char(n2, ','))
print(add_char(n3, ','))
```

Prints:

```
4,567,082
560,867,956
120
```